# Swift sum numbers in array adding from specific element

Tags: arrays, swift, sum

Let's say I have some numbers in an array like below

```
let numberArray = [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 16]
```

I know how to sum them all up by using reduce method but how can I start adding numbers from specific element. For example:

```
//Sum all up by reduce
let sumAll = numberArray.reduce(0, +)
//sumAll = 53 

//I want to start counting from the fourth element in the array which is 6
//so the total should be 45. [6 + 9 + 14 + 16]
```

What method should I use to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either use `dropFirst(_:)` or use a range as the index.

If it's not a fixed number, you could first use `firstIndex(of:)` to determine the index where you want to start.

```
numberArray.dropFirst(3).reduce(0, +)
numberArray[3...].reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: `dropFirst(3)` is safer; it doesn't crash if `numberArray` has fewer than `3` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Run `reduce` on the desired subarray:

```
let numberArray = [1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 16]
let sum = numberArray[3...].reduce(0, +)
```